# call subflow with in mule3 webservice

Tags: mule

I created a Mule3 Simple Front-end Web Service which is supposed to pass the XML message to a sub-flow and returns success to its caller.

mule-config.xml

---

```
<flow name="webserviceTestFlow">
   <http:inbound-endpoint address="${webservicetest.env.endpoint}" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP"/>
  <cxf:simple-service serviceClass="com.test.WebserviceTest" doc:name="SOAP"/>
  <component class="com.test.WebserviceTestImpl" />
</flow>
```

sample webservice method

---

```
public class WebserviceTestImpl implements WebserviceTest,Serializable {
        @Override
    public String test(String requestMessage) throws Exception{
               // sends XML message to a sub-flow
               return "success";
        }
```

The issue is I do not find an mule api to call a sub-flow with in webservice method.

Comment: What are you expected `requestMessage` to contain? The SOAP envelope or whatever parameter passed to the `test` method? I'm asking because you say "pass the XML message to a sub-flow" which is unclear regarding what XML?

Comment: @DavidDossot I mean , whatever passed to the test method

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a `sub-flow` from code is no small feat but possible.

Here is a test component that does invoke a `sub-flow` injected in it:

```
public class TestComponent implements MuleContextAware, FlowConstructAware
{
    private MuleContext muleContext;
    private FlowConstruct flowConstruct;
    private MessageProcessor subFlow;

    public void initialize() throws MuleException
    {
        muleContext.getRegistry().applyProcessorsAndLifecycle(subFlow);
    }

    public String test(final String requestMessage) throws Exception
    {

        final MuleEvent muleEvent = new DefaultMuleEvent(new DefaultMuleMessage(requestMessage, muleContext),
            MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE, flowConstruct);
        final MuleEvent resultEvent = subFlow.process(muleEvent);

        return resultEvent.getMessageAsString();
    }

    public void setMuleContext(final MuleContext muleContext)
    {
        this.muleContext = muleContext;
    }

    public void setFlowConstruct(final FlowConstruct flowConstruct)
    {
        this.flowConstruct = flowConstruct;
    }

    public void setSubFlow(final MessageProcessor subFlow)
    {
        this.subFlow = subFlow;
    }
}
```

The component is configured this way:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean name="testComponent" class="com.example.TestComponent"
        p:subFlow-ref="testSubFlow" init-method="initialize" />
</spring:beans>

...

    <component>
        <spring-object bean="testComponent" />
    </component>
```

Comment: Hi David, I need to call a flow from Java component. I was trying your solution. Where I got stuck is, this `p:subFlow-ref`. How can I get this 'p' namespace?

Comment: @RamBavireddi http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-p-namespace

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using singleton instance to store requestMessage with in test() method of WebserviceTestImpl class and retrieve it in TestSubflow component. I am not sure if it is perfect. but it works:)

Here is how I did it..

mule-config:

---

```
<flow name="webserviceTestFlow">
  <http:inbound-endpoint address="${webservicetest.env.endpoint}" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP"/>
  <cxf:simple-service serviceClass="com.test.WebserviceTest" doc:name="SOAP"/>
  <component class="com.test.WebserviceTestImpl" />
  <flow-ref name="testSubflow"/>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="testSubflow">
    <pooled-component class="com.test.TestSubflow">
        <pooling-profile exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_FAIL" initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ALL" maxActive="1" maxIdle="2" maxWait="3" />
    </pooled-component>
</sub-flow>
```

WebserviceTestImpl and TestSubflow code snippet

---

```
public class WebserviceTestImpl implements WebserviceTest,Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TestMessageProxy testMessageProxy;

    public TriggerTestImpl() {
        this.testMessageProxy = TestMessageProxy.getInstance();
    }
    @Override
    public String test(String requestMessage) throws Exception{
        this.testMessageProxy.setTestMessage(requestMessage);
        return "success";
    }
}

public class TestSubflow  implements Callable{
    private TestMessageProxy testMessageProxy;
    public TestSubflow() {
        this.testMessageProxy = TestMessageProxy.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext context) throws Exception {
        String  testMessage = this.testMessageProxy.getTestMessage();
    }
}
```