# How to invoke sub-flow from a custom transformer (java code)

Tags: mule, esb

How can I invoke (call) a sub-flow from a custom java transformer (from java code)?

Thank you.

Comment: Answered the same recently: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16532977/387927

Comment: Thank you. It's not clear to me how following is initialized in that class:

Comment: private MuleContext muleContext;
    private FlowConstruct flowConstruct;
    private MessageProcessor subFlow;

Comment: Via setters. Mule injects `MuleContext` into `MuleContextAware` classes and `FlowConstruct` into `FlowConstructAware` classes. The sub-flow is injected via standard Spring injection.