# Implementing conditional looping in Mule application

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am new to mule software.I am working in an application in which i need to loop the flow with particular condition. How can i implement while loop in mule application flow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661454/simulate-while-loop-in-mule-3-4).

Comment: below is url for your reference which mimic your requirement
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640243/untilsuccessful-component-to-poll-http-endpoint-till-condition-is-met/28648491#28648491

Answer (score 7):

You can look in to until-successful in mule application.
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope